# Using a variable in is_page(array())

Tags: php, theme-development, array, variables

[Similarly to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161765/not-managing-to-find-a-way-to-use-is-page-with-a-variable-inside-storing-an-ar) I need to extract some page IDs from user input (a theme options admin page), store them in a variable, and then filter using the `is_page()` filter. The input consists of numerical IDs separated by newlines, although if I get this working I'll refactor to allow page slugs too.

Based [on the answer to the linked topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161765/not-managing-to-find-a-way-to-use-is-page-with-a-variable-inside-storing-an-ar), I have the following, But it still does not work. The variable spits out a proper array of IDs, but `is_page()` doesn't filter based on the array.

```
// Wordpress my_conditional_load stuff code above

function my_option_pages() {
  $pages = get_option(esc_textarea('my_conditional_load', ''));
  return $pages; // reusable variable; used in form and also below
}

function my_option_result() {
  $pages = my_option_pages();
  $page = array_map(trim, explode(PHP_EOL, $pages)); // create array; split string at newline
  $result = implode( ', ', $page ); // reassemble as comma delimited list
  $result = rtrim($result); // get rid of extra whitespace
  return $result; // string; resusable variable used below end elsewhere. Must be a string for other uses.
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'test_the_variable' );

function test_the_variable( $content ) {

  $result = my_option_result();
  $result = explode(', ', $result); // recreate the array

  if ( is_page( array( $result ) ) ) {
    echo '<span class="foo hide">Array $result = ';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</span>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<span class="bar hide">Array $result is EMPTY! But we found this: ';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</span>';
  }
  return $content;
}
```

[This page is a working example](https://mercury.photo/contact/). It's page ID 9, which is in the array. Open DevTools and find the string `bar hide` in the page source. You can see the array:

```
<span class="bar hide">Array $result is EMPTY! But we found this: Array
  (
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 6604
    [2] => 6509
    [3] => 7323
  )
</span>
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Are the other IDs also pages? Also, are you _on_ the Page (and it is a Page post type, correct?) with ID 9 when testing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `is_page` you are passing an array with one element that is also an array. Since $result is already an array, you should do

```
if ( is_page( $result ) ){
```

Comment: I just figured that out on my own! But glad I asked anyway so this answer will be available to the next mook trying to solve this!